# Ribbon grayed out partially if https context

Tags: ribbon, https, reverse-proxy

we have a proxy-server running which routes all the external-traffic in a ssl-context since we are using basic-authetication for external users. For internal users we have kerberos and http running.
Unfortunately if im connecting from outside, almost every ribbon-buttn is grayed out.
[image: see here]

If the user is from the intranet, can use kerberos and normal http everything works fine..

these dudes had the same issue but unfortunately there is no solution or hint..
http://forums.citrix.com/thread.jspa?threadID=303918

To narrow it more down, i experience that the notification box is stuck in loading condition when i expand the dropdown menu for a list item in a document library. See in screen below
[image: notification error]

Comment: This is a weird one, try emailing the guy on the Citrix forum who had the issue, perhaps he has solved it now?

Comment: Proxy server is almost certainly the culprit here, the fact that you're using basic auth is also contributing to this problem I would wager.

Comment: Because of proxy probably javascripts are not loading. You can check your console for error and check network trafic to see if scripts are loading.

Comment: i did this yesterday and some js errors came up. somehow i get http context back and browser prompts an insecure error.. im currently diggin into it and will provide the solution when i got it ;) somehow i messed up the AAM configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emailed one of the guys from the citrix board.
He supported me with this file: http://www.f5.com/pdf/deployment-guides/f5-sharepoint-2010-dg.pdf

Important are pages 1-4 to 1-7.

Basically its pretty simple stuff. i just changed the public url to https and added an internal url with http.. solved my issues.

ribbon loads properly and context menu is available as well!